# Modify .txt files, save originals and move modified

Tags: python, python-3.x, copy, os.path, python-os

I modify many .txt files by adding string at the end of them. 
How to save the original files and then move and rename modified ones? 
I use `os` library.

```py
i - iterated .txt files
new_name is variable consiting of random numbers
path=os.getcwd()
dirName=('new_directory')
```

This code only move files:

```py
old_file = os.path.join(path, str(i)) 
new_path = os.path.join(path, dirName) 
new_file = os.path.join(new_path, new_name) 
os.rename(old_file, new_file)
```

I would like to use also `os` library to move and rename modified files.

Here is my whole code:

```py
import os
import random

pressure=('Added pressure:')
dirName=('new_directory')
path=os.getcwd()

try:
    os.mkdir(dirName)
    print("Done: "+dirName) 
except FileExistsError:
    print("Directory" + dirName +" exist")

list=[]
for file in os.listdir("./"): 
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
        lista.append(file)

for i in list:
    f = open(i,"r")    
    file_contents = f.read()   
    print(f.read())
    f.close()
    if(pressure in file_contents):  
        print('It was added!')
    else:
        file=open(i, 'a') 
        rand_press=(str(random.randrange(980, 1040, 5))) #
        rand_temp=(str(round(random.uniform(18, 26),2))) 
        press_and_temp=('Added pressure: \t'+rand_press+' mbar\n'+'Added temperature: \t'+rand_temp+' degC\n')
        file.write(press_and_temp) 
        file.close()
        new_name=str(rand_temp+'_'+rand_press+'.txt')
        old_file = os.path.join(path, str(i)) 
        new_path = os.path.join(path, dirName) 
        new_file = os.path.join(new_path, new_name) 
        os.rename(old_file, new_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two suggestions.

1) Copy the file to a new location. Modify the second file. https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html

2) Read the file, store it in some variable. Close the file. Create a new file in a new location, write to the file with your modifications, save it. https://www.guru99.com/reading-and-writing-files-in-python.html